# how model info is sent to keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

below is the code in tensorflow document.
(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

in tf.keras.Model, input and output tensor related info is sent.

But there is no info about modeling( two dense layer and activation funtion)

How modeling info is sent to tf.keras.Model??

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ouputs doesn't only have informations about the output of the network.
It includes the graph built with the the layers you have.

When you create a network with the following code, you pass the complete graph with each new call:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
# First step
layers = tf.keras.Dense(100)(inputs)
# Second step
layers = tf.keras.Dense(100)(layers)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(layers)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

In the first step, the graph inside layers is the following:
Input -­> Dense
In the second step, the graph inside layers is the following:
Input -> Dense -> Dense
Etc...